# RouterContext - Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have wrapped my app with BrowserRouter , but when try to export the app `withRouter ( App )` , i'm getting below error on the browser

```
  16 | return (
  17 |   <RouterContext.Consumer>
  18 |     {context => {
> 19 |       invariant(
     | ^  20 |         context,
  21 |         `You should not use <${displayName} /> outside a <Router>`
  22 |       );
```

And my App is

```
function App() {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);
  let routes =(
    <Switch>           
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} /> 
        <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>

  );

  if(!appState){
    routes=(
      <Switch>
          
           <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
    )
  }
  
  return ( 
     <React.Fragment> 
      <BrowserRouter >        
      <Navigation /> 
      <SocialBar />
      
      <main className={classes.container}>
             <Suspense fallback={<p>loading...</p>}>
                {routes}
              </Suspense>     
      </main>

      <Footer className={classes.Footer}/>   
      </BrowserRouter >
    </React.Fragment>    
  ); 
}  

export default  withRouter ( App );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have wrapped my app with BrowserRouter

You havn't though. The BrowserRouter is part of the return statement *inside* `App`. This will allow any descendants of `App` to use `withRouter`, but `App` itself can not.

If `App` is the top component in your component tree, then it can never use `withRouter`. If you need `App` to use `withRouter`, then you'll need to move `BrowserRouter` higher up the component tree, thus making App no longer the top of the component tree.

Though I should point out: `App` isn't actually using any props, so you don't seem to need `withRouter`. Your fix may be as simple as to stop using `withRouter` on this component.

Comment: HI Nicholas, i added `withRouter` because  i'm not able to use ` props.history.push('home');`  and i got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: moving browserRouter outside app, fixed this error. but still i'm not able to use `props.history.push('home');`

Comment: I'm able to solve it by changing as below `<Route path="/faq" render={props => <Faq  {...props} />}  /> `

Answer (score 1):

Its simple actually.

The App component is technically outside of the Router scope, only the components inside of it are. If you want to make this work you should wrap index.js inside the BrowserRouter.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```